# Not able to add OnManipulationEnded via Script(MRTK)

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I am trying to add the Manipulation event (OnManipulationEnded) via script.
Below is the event I wanted to add.
[image]

I am trying to add this via below script:

```
mainobject.AddComponent<ObjectManipulator>();
mainobject.GetComponent<ObjectManipulator>().OnManipulationEnded.AddListener(() => new_position());
```

But this is the error that I am getting:
CS1593  Delegate 'UnityAction' does not take 0 arguments.
I do not know what arguments I need to pass

I want a new position after Gameobject is manipulated from Position A to Position B.
I have created a new function to calculate the new Positions. I want this function to be called once Manipulation is ended.

I am very new to C# and Unity. Can someone please help?

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [ManipulationEvent Class (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.ui.manipulationevent?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0). This event has the default callback argument **ManipulationEventData**. So, this argument must be included in your custom function. You can refer to [Unity - Scripting API: UnityEvent (unity3d.com)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html) and the following methods.

```
ObjectManipulator objectManipulator;
void Start()
{
    objectManipulator = GetComponent<ObjectManipulator>();
    objectManipulator.OnManipulationEnded.AddListener(TouchEnded);//1
    objectManipulator.OnManipulationEnded.AddListener((data) => TouchEnded(data));//2
    objectManipulator.OnManipulationEnded.AddListener((data) =>{ });//3
}
private void TouchEnded(ManipulationEventData arg)
{
   
}
```